# Toolbar transparente em uma activity apenas

Tags: android

Tenho um xml chamado toolbar, e reutilizo ele em todas as minhas telas chamando o

`<include layout="@layout/toolbar" />`

Em uma tela específica gostaria que o toolbar ficasse transparente, mas com um leve sombreamento.

Como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Artur, no caso dessa imagem que você colocou, ela utiliza um `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Se você deseja o mesmo efeito presente na imagem, faça o seguinte:

Adicione as dependências no seu `build.gradle`:

**build.gradle**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

Na sua activity que você deseja ter o efeito, você vai precisar colocar sua toolbar dentro do `CollapsingToolbarLayout`:

**MainActivity.java**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/MyAppbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp" <!-- height of appbar -->
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/MyToolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <!-- Coloque seus componentes aqui -->

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Veja que no exemplo utilizamos um `CoordinatorLayout`, ele é o responsável por coordenar todo o trabalho entre as views dentro dele, inclusive o efeito que você deseja na **toolbar**.

Na `NestedScrollView` utilizamos o `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` para que você tenha o efeito de expandir e guardar a toolbar conforme o usuário move a lista na tela.

Se você quiser também, é possível fazer com que o layout continue sempre expandido, como o da sua imagem.

---

**Veja mais nos link's abaixo:**

[Collapsing Toolbars Android Example](http://www.feelzdroid.com/2015/08/collapsing-toolbars-android-example.html)

[Mastering the Coordinator Layout](http://saulmm.github.io/mastering-coordinator)

Comment: Tentei fazer aqui, mas quando tento adicionar o build.gradle dá o seguinte erro:


`cError:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:23.4.0
<a href="install.m2.repo">Install Repository and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:/Users/artur/Desktop/CollapsingToolbarLayout/app/build.gradle">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>`

Comment: Clique no link do erro para instalar o repositório, ou abra o SDK Manager e atualize o Android Support Library.

Comment: Sim, foi a primeira coisa que vi. Ele solicita para sair do Android Studio e logo após abre o SDK Manager, mas lá todos os repositórios já estão instalados. Não tem nada para instalar ou atualizar.

Comment: Qual a versão que está instalada no seu Support Library?

Comment: Versão 30. quando abro o SDK Manager ele da um erro. 

`Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
Fetching https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/addons_list-2.xml, reason: peer not authenticated
Fetching URL: https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml
Failed to fetch URL https://dl.google.com/android/repository/repository-11.xml, reason: SSLPeerUnverified peer not authenticated

`

Comment: Tenta colocar a última versão 24.0.0 no lugar de 23.4.0. Quanto ao erro do SDK manager, vá em tools > options e marque a opção "Force https://... sources to be fetched using http"

Comment: Consegui resolver. Mandei instalar direto pelo android studio, nao fui para o SDK Manager. Agora não entendi o que você falou. Você quer que eu coloque o meu toolbar dentro deste xml ?

Comment: Veja novamente o xml da `Activity`, tem uma toolbar dentro do `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, você pode substituir ela pela sua, só não esqueça de adicionar o efeito parallax: `app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"`. Seria melhor você criar um novo projeto com esse código para você aprender mais sobre esse layout, e depois implementar no seu. Dá uma olhada nesse .gif para ver o efeito funcionando: http://androcode.es/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/simple_coordinator.gif

Comment: Leonardo. Obrigado pela ajuda. Vou em aprofundar mais nesse assunto Collapsing Toolbars.